# How to add drop shadow with Transparency like this photo (Photoshop) ?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, transparency, drop-shadow

I am not expert in Photoshop. But I am trying to do a drop show like this..

[image: Drop Shadow with Transparency]

I am trying to make Shopify Logo Like this .. I mean Transparent with drop shadow like this..

Shopify Logo : 
[image: Shopify Logo]

Please help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: You simply want to add a drop shadow to the shopify logo, is that correct?

Comment: Ok maybe its just me but there is many ways to interpret your question. Any of [these](http://i.imgur.com/50DkICH.png) by any chance?

Comment: No. I want to make it Transparent like WP logo and want to add drop shadow like wp logo.. 

I can make it Transparent but How i can add drop shadow like wp logo ?

Comment: @Saiful so you men the one on the right in my examples?

Comment: @joojaa Thanks .. Yes . That's it .. Can you make a border for missing shape ? http://imgur.com/a/BjlaS . Thanks .. How  can i make this ?

Comment: @Saiful like [this](http://i.imgur.com/fFnIZMT.png)?

Comment: @joojaa Thanks. Old one is better. Can you please help me how can i make like this ? Thanks

Comment: @joojaa How can i make like this ? Please help me ..

Comment: I'm sorry but GD.SE is not a website to get free work or step-by-step tutorials. It's very nice that @joojaa is helping you but I think you have enough to try it on your own.

Comment: I closed your question for several reasons.  1)It would appear you're requesting free work.  2) You show a shopify icon that I do not see a shadow on except for the side itself so I'm unsure if you're asking just for the S to be done.  3) You don't show what you've tried and to answer this would take a long tutorial.  After reading your and joojaa's communication you can make an edit explaining better what your desire is and where you are needing further assistance and we can reopen it to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply create the logo shape and add the effect drop shadow,
where you can adjust the opacity, color, distance etc of the shadow

[image]